When training the same model on an MNIST dataset and a Kaggle dataset, the accuracy of the MNIST is >90, and the accuracy of the kaggle is <15
I have a code that is working perfectly with the MNIST handwritten digit dataset, and when I load it and train it everything is fine.
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784')
X, Y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
X = np.array(X) # just in case…
Y = np.array(Y) # just in case…



X = X / 255 - 0.5

Y_new = DLModel.to_one_hot(10,Y)
print(Y_new.shape)

m = 60000
m_test = X.shape[0] - m
X_train, X_test = X[:m].T, X[m:].T
Y_train, Y_test = Y_new[:,:m], Y_new[:,m:]

print(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape, Y_test.shape)


np.random.seed(111)
shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(m)
X_train, Y_train = X_train[:, shuffle_index], Y_train[:, shuffle_index]

np.random.seed(1)

Hidden = DLNeuronsLayer("Hidden",64,28*28,"sigmoid",0.1,'adaptive')
Output = DLNeuronsLayer("Output",10,64,"softmax",0.1,'adaptive')

digit_network = DLNetwork("digit_net")
digit_network.add_layer(Hidden)
digit_network.add_layer(Output)

digit_model = DLModel("model",digit_network,'categorical_cross_entropy')
costs = digit_model.train(X_train, Y_train, 200)
u10.print_costs(costs,200)

When I print the costs graph and the confusion matrix it shows a normal graph.
Costs Graph
The problem arrives when I try to switch the dataset from MNIST to Kaggle. I first loaded the dataset on google collab, and loaded it like this:
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

import os
import random
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def array_to_image(array):
    # Check if the array size is correct for a 28x28 image
    if array.size != 28 * 28:
        raise ValueError("The input array must have 784 elements (28x28).")
    
    # Reshape the array back into a 28x28 image
    image = array.reshape(28, 28)
    
    # Display the image
    plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
    plt.axis('off')  # Hide the axis
    plt.show()
    
    return image

def load_handwritten_digits(data_dir):
    data = []
    labels = []

    all_files = []
    for digit in range(10):
        digit_dir = os.path.join(os.path.join(data_dir, str(digit)), str(digit))
        digit_files = [os.path.join(digit_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(digit_dir) if f.endswith('.png')]
        all_files.extend([(f, digit) for f in digit_files])

    random.shuffle(all_files)

    for file_path, digit in all_files:
        try:
            # Open the image
            img = Image.open(file_path)
            # print(f"Loaded image: {file_path}, mode: {img.mode}, size: {img.size}")
            
            # Convert image to RGBA if it's not already
            if img.mode != 'RGBA':
                img = img.convert('RGBA')
            
            # Split the image into its separate channels
            r, g, b, a = img.split()
            
            # Invert the RGB channels
            r = r.point(lambda p: 255 - p)
            g = g.point(lambda p: 255 - p)
            b = b.point(lambda p: 255 - p)
            
            # Merge the channels back, keeping the alpha channel unchanged
            inverted_img = Image.merge("RGBA", (r, g, b, a))
            
            # Create a black background image
            black_bg = Image.new("RGBA", img.size, (0, 0, 0, 255))
            
            # Paste the inverted image onto the black background using the alpha channel as mask
            black_bg.paste(inverted_img, (0, 0), inverted_img)
            
            # Convert to grayscale
            img = black_bg.convert('L')
            img_data = np.array(img).astype(np.float32) / 255.0
            
            # Debugging step: Print min and max values to check normalization
            # print(f"Converted Image: {file_path}, min: {img_data.min()}, max: {img_data.max()}")
            
            # Display the image to debug if necessary
            # array_to_image(img_data * 255)  # Convert back to 0-255 for display
            
            data.append(img_data.flatten())
            labels.append(str(digit))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error loading file: {file_path}")
            print(e)

    data = np.array(data)
    labels = np.array(labels)

    return data, labels


# Load images and labels
base_folder = 'dataset'
X, Y = load_handwritten_digits(base_folder)


(The displaying is just checking the everything has been loaded correctly, And everything else in the code is exactly the same)
Now for some reason, when I load the Kaggle dataset, the costs never go below 2 (When they should go way below 0.001), and the costs graph looks like this:
Costs image of kaggle
Am I doing something wrong whilst loading the dataset? I've tried everything to match the Kaggle dataset to look exactly like the MNIST dataset.
